# Let R be a ring with unit element, R not necessarily commutative, such that the only right-ideals of R are (0) and R. Prove that R is a division ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with unit element, $R$ not necessarily commutative, such
that the only right-ideals of R are $(0)$ and $R.$ Prove that R is a division ring.

This was a problem from the book, "Topics in Algebra" by I.N Herstein from Chapter- 3 (Ring Theory) , Page number- 139 (2nd Edition).

So, we basically need to show that the non-zero elements of $R$ forms a group under multiplication. This means we only need to prove that each non-zero element of $R$ has an inverse.

I tried solving the problem as follows:

Given, $R$ is a ring with unit element, we consider an $a\neq 0\in R$. Then $aR=\{ar:a\in R\}$ is a right ideal of $R.$ Since, $aR\neq 0$ so, $aR=R.$ This means that every element of $R$ can be expressed as a multiple of $a.$ In particular, as $1\in R$ $\exists b\in R$ such that $ab=1.$

---

Now, I need to show somehow, that $ba=1$ as well because, $b$ is the inverse of $a$ iff $ab=ba=1.$ But this is the point where I am stuck. Things get difficult for ne because $R$ is not necessarily commutative. So, I do not get how to proceed further.

Comment: Consider the annihilator $\{ r : ar = 0 \}$ and show that it's a right ideal, hence must be zero. This means that left multiplication by $a$ is an injection, which means concretely that you can cancel $a$ on the left from two sides of an equation. Now, starting from $ab = 1$ you get that $aba = a$...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Are you using a non-zero $a$ in $R$? I think a little bit of an elaboration is demanded :)

Comment: "So, we basically need to show that the non-zero elements of $R$ forms an abelian group under multiplication." Why should $R-\{0\}$ be abelian?

Comment: @Thomas: I'm using the same $a$ you are, continuing from your argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is true for a ring with exactly two right ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334028/what-is-true-for-a-ring-with-exactly-two-right-ideals) (see solution to question); see also the solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151319/trivial-right-or-left-ideals-of-r-imply-that-r-is-a-division-ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ideal generated by $b (\neq 0)$

\begin{equation}
(b) = R \implies \exists c \in R \text{ such that } bc = 1
\end{equation}

We have
\begin{equation}
ab = 1, bc = 1 \implies abc = c \implies a = c
\end{equation}

Thererfore, $ba = 1$